# Check array for values equal or very close to zero

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have a one dimensional `numpy` array for which I need to find out if *any value* is zero or very close to it.
With this line I can check for zeros rapidly:

```
if 0. in my_array:
    # do something
```

but I also have very small elements like 1.e-22 which I would also like to treat as zeros (otherwise I get a *Divide by zero* warning further down the road)

Say my threshold is 1.e-6 and I want to efficiently check if *any* value in my array is smaller than that. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no reason to loop in Python; just broadcast the abs and the < and use [`np.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

```
np.any(np.absolute(my_array) < eps)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using this for testing you can use [numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal.html)

As the document says it uses a method similar to @phihag suggests:

```
any(abs(x) < 0.5 * 10**(-decimal))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this often, you should try to use searchsorted, or if you have scipy `KDTree` (or `cKDTree` depending on the version), to speed things up.