# Assert array almost equal zero

Tags: python, arrays, unit-testing, assert

I'm writing unit tests for my simulation and want to check that for specific parameters the result, a numpy array, is zero. Due to calculation inaccuracies, small values are also accepted (1e-7). What is the best way to assert this array is close to 0 in all places?

- `np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(a, np.zeros(a.shape))` and `assert_allclose` fail as the relative tolerance is `inf` (or 1 if you switch the arguments) [Docu](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_allclose.html)
- I feel like `np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal_nulp(a, np.zeros(a.shape))` is not precise enough as it compares the difference to the spacing, therefore it's always true for `nulps >= 1` and false otherways but does not say anything about the amplitude of `a` [Docu](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal_nulp.html)
- Use of `np.testing.assert_(np.all(np.absolute(a) < 1e-7))` based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328537/check-array-for-values-equal-or-very-close-to-zero) does not give any of the detailed output, I am used to by other `np.testing` methods

Is there another way to test this? Maybe another testing package?

Comment: Why can't you use the absolute tolerance argument in `assert_allclose` for this?

Comment: Thanks, @MrBeanBremen, you are totally right. Can you post it as answer, so I can accept it?
I'm sorry, I did not think about this easy solution.

Comment: Also, the contruction with `np.zeros` does not work, it's probably better to use [`np.zeros_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you compare a numpy array with all zeros, you can use the absolute tolerance, as the relative tolerance does not make sense here:

```py
from numpy.testing import assert_allclose

def test_zero_array():
    a = np.array([0, 1e-07, 1e-08])
    assert_allclose(a, 0, atol=1e-07)
```

The `rtol` value does not matter in this case, as it is multiplied with 0 if calculating the tolerance:

```
atol + rtol * abs(desired)
```

*Update*: Replaced `np.zeros_like(a)` with the simpler scalar 0. As pointed out by @hintze, np array comparisons also work against scalars.

Comment: minor thing, but still: `assert_allclose` can compare ND arrays and scalars, so no need to use `np.zeros_like()` ;)

Comment: @hintze - Thanks, good catch! I adapted the answer accordingly.